# Excel Commission Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Wondering if I could get help getting the correct formula to figure out the `comm%` based off the price it was sold at.

Basically, there are **two spreadsheets**.

**First one** is our price grid to show what the commission pct will be:

```
Product  -  20%  -  15%   -  10%
Widget 1 -  3990 -  3490  -  3090
Widget 2 -  4990 -  4490  -  4090
Widget 3 -  5990 -  5490  -  5090
```

**The second spreadsheet** would list the Products sold and at what price it was sold at:

```
Widget 2 - $4690
Widget 3 - $5100
Widget 1 - $4000
```

I was thinking `INDEX/MATCH`.  I can do the `MATCH` correctly to find the correct row, but I'm not sure how to incorporate that price range lookup into the formula.

In the example I gave above the commission should be 15%, 10% & 20% respectively.

Need to create a formula that matches the Product and then takes the price sold at and matches it to what column it would fall under and give me the % for that column.

I've spent weeks search the net and I can only get half way there. The MATCH to figure out which row the Product is on is simple, it's the price matching that's got me stumped.

Thanks.

Comment: If the item sold is *below* the price in 10% column, then there's no commission, correct? If it's between the 10% and 15% column, you get 10%? Can you clarify a little more how the commission will work?

Comment: Ok to use **`VBA`**?

Comment: Correct.  Anything below the 10% column would be 0%.  In between 10 & 15 would be 10%.  Between 15 and 20 would be 15% and anything at the 20% column or higher would be 20%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this by making use of the rarely used Hlookup function, using it's range_lookup option. The only requirement for it is that you reorder your commission data from low% to high%. like this:

```
Product     10%     15%     20%
Widget 1    3090    3490    3990
Widget 2    4090    4490    4990
Widget 3    5090    5490    5990
```

If you've done this, you can use this formula to get the correct commission

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1;0;MATCH(HLOOKUP(INT(SUBSTITUTE(B1; "$"; ""));INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&MATCH(A1;Sheet1!$A:$A ) & ":" & MATCH(A1;Sheet1!$A:$A ));1; TRUE);INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&MATCH(A1;Sheet1!$A:$A ) & ":" & MATCH(A1;Sheet1!$A:$A)) )-1)
```

**This is the breakdown:**

Format input as integer (commission data is int, values are $)

```
SUBSTITUTE(B1; "$"; "")
```

Use the input to put together the reference row for the Hlookup. We use indirect to add the sheetname and ":" to the reference.

```
INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&MATCH(A1;Sheet1!$A:$A ) & ":" & MATCH(A1;Sheet1!$A:$A ))
```

Use Hlookup to find the matching value:

```
HLOOKUP(INT(SUBSTITUTE(B1; "$"; ""));INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&MATCH(A1;Sheet1!$A:$A ) & ":" & MATCH(A1;Sheet1!$A:$A ));1; TRUE)
```

Use the found value in a horizontal match function to find the used column, and substract 1:

```
MATCH(<hlookup>; INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&MATCH(A1;Sheet1!$A:$A ) & ":" & MATCH(A1;Sheet1!$A:$A))) - 1
```

Use Offset to find the matching value

```
Offset(Sheet1!$A$1;0; <match>)
```

Comment: I tried running that formula you supplied but it gives the answer of 0 every time.  You have MATCH(A1;Sheet1!$A:$A listed in 4 spots which is matching the widget part.  Should there be some thing trying to match the amount in B1?

Comment: That would be the Substitute(B1; "$"; "") we started out with

Comment: Forgot to mention I've broken up your sample data into multiple columns. So Sheet 1 (commission %) would have columns A, B, C, D (resp. Product, 10%, 15% and 20%) and your Sheet 2 (Product sold list) would have Product and price. Breaking up these lines should exactly match your product name, so sheet1.Product "Widget 1" should match sheet2.Product"Widget 1"

Comment: I played around with it some more and got it to partially work.  I placed the formula on Sheet2 cell C1. The first row the output is correct, but when I copy the formula down, it grabs the result from row2 of Sheet1 (399000%).  It's grabbing the result from the correct column, but it should always be row1 where the percentages are.

Comment: Never mind.  I copied your Offset formula wrong.  I did $A$A instead of $A$1.  Works perfect.  Thanks